# Corda community version with SQL or NoSQL database connection for node and notary

Tags: corda, corda-flow

How can I save the txns details into DB for each node and notary?

I am using the Corda community 4.9 version.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Corda community version supports Postgres 13.8 Full platform support page at: https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.10/community/release-platform-support-matrix.html